# BinaryReader есть ли timeout?

Tags: c#, tcp

Есть ли способ, как можно установить время ожидания для `BinaryReader`?

Когда неожиданно происходит разрыв соединения, а затем его восстановление, программа-клиент шлёт данные, а вот серверная часть на `BinaryReader.Read` зависает и программа не идёт дальше этой строки. Как только все клиенты отсоединяются, программа оживает и начинает всё подгружать, как-будто из кэша какого-то и в конечном итоге выдаёт исключение о том, что удаленный клиент внезапно разорвал соединение.

Comment: А покажите код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно это: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14378242/276994

Comment: @VladD, код простой: TcpClien+NetworkStream отсылают, TcpListener+NetworkStream+BinaryReader получают значения.Минимум лишней обвязки. Сделал как Вы посоветовали в ссылке, добавил TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout в нужное мне значение и программа перестала долго висеть. Спасибо!

Comment: Отлично, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить таймаут для самого `BinaryReader`'а нельзя, но можно установить таймаут для `TcpClient`'а, котоорый поставляет ему несущий поток.

Для этого имеет смысл воспользоваться параметром [`TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout.aspx) *до* запроса `NetworkStream`'а.

Ответ честно украден [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14378242/276994).